# Remote Desktop to DC from client with upgraded GPO security

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

Applied some new required policies to our GPO and can't figure out why I can't login remotely using RDC to our DC (Server 2008 R2). I am getting this error from my clients.

```
Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy
```

I have checked User Rights assignment and I am added to the group it allows.
I have checked Security options:

- Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only (Disabled and enabled has no effect)
- Microsoft network server: Disconnect clients when logon hours expire is enabled. (Disabled and enabled has no effect) (I can login at all hours BTW).

Checking event longs shows that when I try to connect I get logon type 10 and it says unknown account/bad password. It doesn't even let me type my password in when I connect. So I am confused as to what is going on. What am I missing in my GPO

Comment: Have you tried to reverse your policy changes?

Comment: @Ramhound trying that right now.

Comment: @Ramhound old policies allow me in without a problem.

Comment: So apply each policy change, one by one, in order to find the conflicting policy.  Provide us with that policy so we can explain the reason you have a conflict.

Comment: @Ramhound So far the policy on my DCs are fine. When I apply the policy to my Local computers is what is preventing the connection.

Comment: I understand when you make all the changes together it stops working, but have you tried my suggestion, turning each policy on until you find the conflicting policy?

Comment: yes I have been doing one at a time. I might have found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was found to be the following Group Policy setting on the local computer clients.

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Systems > Credential Delegation > Restrict delegation of credentials to remote servers.
```

Originally set to **Enabled**. Changed it to **Disabled**. And was able to remote to my servers.

Answer (score 1):

As an added issue, if you use Hyper-V on Windows 10 and you try to RDP into an enhanced session **Restrict delegation of credentials to remote servers** break **Enhanced Session** functionl when using the VMConnect client.